# table_method how to check left outer join field is null

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, left-join

I have a generated admin module with the following table method

```
class Exam{
```

...

```
function retrieveExamList(Doctrine_Query $q){

    $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias();
    return $q->
    innerJoin("$rootAlias.Person p")->
    innerJoin("$rootAlias.Code ec")->
    leftJoin ("$rootAlias.Order order")
    ->leftJoin("order.LatestVmOrderDetail od")->
    addSelect("$rootAlias.*, p.*, ec.*, ec.name as exam_code_name, "
    ."order.order_id, od.payment_status, od.payment_date, od.payment_method_id"
    );

}
```

In the admin list view, $exam->getPaymentStatus() returns null if the outer join returns null, what is the recommended way to check for this?

```
$exam->_data['payment_status'] === null
```

or is there something better?

I have tried

```
if ($exam->getPaymentStatus()){
```

which returns a Fatal error.

My problem is specifically that I have an order number in exam, but that order number doesn't exist in the corresponding relation

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a simple if like this:

```
if ($exam->getPaymentStatus()) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Call to a member function getPaymentStatus() on a non-object